# ellipse with images inside

Tags: math-mode

I'm struggling to get such result in my work but I don't know where to start. Is there someone who can help me with it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE. This figure can easily be drawn with TikZ, the fit and shapes.geometric libraries may be useful to fit ellipses around the red dots.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not really that good on Tikz. If you can help me with some start codes that I can develop on my self. Inside the ellipse, I need other images than dots.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a `just-do-it-for-me` class of question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,fit,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7,transform shape,bullet/.style={circle,inner sep=0.25em},
pics/5ness/.style={code={
\path (0,0) node[bullet,fill=red] (#1-b4) {} foreach \X in {0,...,3}
{(-\X*60:0.6) node[bullet,fill=red] (#1-b\X) {}};
\node[ellipse,draw,fit=(#1-b3) (#1-b2) (#1-b0),inner xsep=0pt] (fit-#1){};
}}]
\path foreach \Y in {0,...,4} { (\Y*2.5,0) pic {5ness=\Y}};
\end{tikzpicture}\]
\boldmath
\[ \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(F.base)]
\node[text=blue] (F){$\mathit{5\quad+\quad5\quad+\quad5\quad+\quad5}$};
\draw[blue,thick,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] (F.south west) -- (F.south east)
node[midway,below,font=\itshape\bfseries]{something French};
\end{tikzpicture}
~=~\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(X.base)]
\node[fill=white,draw,rounded corners=0.2ex,text=red,inner color=white,outer
color=gray!20] (X){$
\mathsf{5\times5~=~20}$};
\draw[red,thick,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror},overlay] (X.south west) -- (X.south)
node[midway,below,font=\itshape\bfseries]{something};
\end{tikzpicture}\]
\unboldmath
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or a more mathematically sound computation with big thanks to Zarko.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,fit,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9,transform shape,bullet/.style={circle,inner sep=0.25em},
pics/5ness/.style={code={
\path (0,0) node[bullet,fill=red] (#1-b4) {} foreach \X in {0,...,3}
{(-\X*60:0.6) node[bullet,fill=red] (#1-b\X) {}};
\node[ellipse,draw,fit=(#1-b3) (#1-b2) (#1-b0),inner xsep=0pt] (fit-#1){};
}}]
\path foreach \Y in {0,...,3} { (\Y*2.5,0) pic {5ness=\Y}};
\end{tikzpicture}\]
\boldmath
\[ \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(F.base)]
\node[text=blue] (F){$\mathit{5\quad+\quad5\quad+\quad5\quad+\quad5}$};
\draw[blue,thick,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] (F.south west) -- (F.south east)
node[midway,below,font=\itshape\bfseries]{something French};
\end{tikzpicture}
~=~\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(X.base)]
\node[fill=white,draw,rounded corners=0.2ex,text=red,inner color=white,outer
color=gray!20] (X){$
\mathsf{5\times4~=~20}$};
\draw[red,thick,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror},overlay] (X.south west) -- (X.south)
node[midway,below,font=\itshape\bfseries]{something};
\end{tikzpicture}\]
\unboldmath
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ` 5 x 5 = 25` ...  :-)

Comment: @Zarko :-):-) My upvote there is although 5 x 5=20 :-)

Comment: @Zarko Good point! (My computation is correct, *after* tax ;-)